# Is it possible to attach a file to an email from the command line?

Tags: macos, mail.app, uti

I am often using the terminal, and I'd like to be able type a command that will attach a selected file to an email in mail.app.

```
:~ mailme myfile
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command

```
open -a Mail.app [filename(s)]
```

opens a "New Message" window in Mail.app, with the `filename(s)` attached.

Comment: FYI: you can do ```open -a Mail.app `ls *.pdf` ``` to put the reuslts of `ls` into the mail

Answer (score 5):

Works also with Thunderbird

```
open -a Thunderbird filename
```

It seems that yout can attach only one file to a new e-mail.

Comment: Could you give an example for `open -a Thunderbird [filename(s)]` . I tried the following but none worked open -a Thunderbird ["filename1","filename2"] open -a Thunderbird [filename1,filename2] open -a Thunderbird ['filename1','filename2'] for single files `open -a Thunderbird filename` works like a charm.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I did't tested it before posting. It seems attaching more files doesn't work. I'll edit the answer.